# unable to type into textarea generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, textarea

Got a tinymce textarea being generated dynamically pretty well but unable to type into any of the generated textareas.

jsFiddle to preview:

http://jsfiddle.net/sammie85/KyNtB/

Each textarea have unique Ids but just cant figure out what could be issue.

**Here is the JS in HTML head:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  var removeLink = ' <a class="remove" href="#" style="float:right; margin-top:-20px; margin-bottom:10px;" onclick="$(this).parent().slideUp(function(){ $(this).remove() }); return false">remove</a>';
$('a.add').relCopy({ append: removeLink});  
});
</script>
```

**HTML form:**

```
<form name = "form2" method="post" action="">

<div class="clone_box_holder cloneEmp">

<p>
<label><strong>New Text</strong></label>
<textarea id="textarea_id" name="content[]">
<?php echo stripslashes($content); ?>
</textarea>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</p>

</div>

<p><a href="#" class="add add_res_submit" rel=".cloneEmp">Add More Text</a></p>

</form>
```

**JS generating new textarea:**

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.relCopy = function(options) {
        var settings = jQuery.extend({
            excludeSelector: ".exclude",
            emptySelector: ".empty",
            copyClass: "copy",
            append: '',
            clearInputs: true,
            limit: 0 // 0 = unlimited
        }, options);

        settings.limit = parseInt(settings.limit);

        // loop each element
        this.each(function() {

            // set click action
            $(this).click(function(){
                var rel = $(this).attr('rel'); // rel in jquery selector format             
                var counter = $(rel).length;

                // stop limit
                if (settings.limit != 0 && counter >= settings.limit){
                    return false;
                };

                var master = $(rel+":first");
                var parent = $(master).parent();                        
                var clone = $(master).clone(true).addClass(settings.copyClass+counter).append(settings.append);

                //Remove Elements with excludeSelector
                if (settings.excludeSelector){
                    $(clone).find(settings.excludeSelector).remove();
                };

                //Empty Elements with emptySelector
                if (settings.emptySelector){
                    $(clone).find(settings.emptySelector).empty();
                };                              

                // Increment Clone IDs
                if ( $(clone).attr('id') ){
                    var newid = $(clone).attr('id') + (counter +1);
                    $(clone).attr('id', newid);
                };

                // Increment Clone Children IDs
                $(clone).find('[id]').each(function(){
                    var newid = $(this).attr('id') + (counter +1);
                    $(this).attr('id', newid);
                });

                //Clear Inputs/Textarea
                if (settings.clearInputs){
                    $(clone).find(':input').each(function(){
                        var type = $(this).attr('type');
                        switch(type)
                        {
                            case "button":
                                break;
                            case "reset":
                                break;
                            case "submit":
                                break;
                            case "checkbox":
                                $(this).attr('checked', '');
                                break;
                            default:
                              $(this).val("");
                        }                       
                    });                 
                };

                $(parent).find(rel+':last').after(clone);

                return false;

            }); // end click action

        }); //end each loop

        return this; // return to jQuery
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Would really appreciate getting help.

Comment: Instead of linking to your temp site, can you add a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsFiddle.net) (or similar) to demonstrate the issue as we cannot change your site's code to test different solutions.

Comment: Threw a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LhtJ4/) together (feel free to add the css and add it to your question) and it seems to work as expected. Can you check your console to see if you get any errors as something else must be the cause of this.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Will place in jsFiddle.

Comment: I have added a link to view it on jsFiddle... Hope to get a response as soon as you can.... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can't clone the HTML with the already TinyMCE editor injected by the plugin. This link mentions it in the within the many comments: [**http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=26372**](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=26372).

`remove` as mentioned in the link did not work for me in your code, maybe you can get it to work. In the meantime see below for an alternative I use myself when duplicating DOM elements which have third party plugins attached.

You can make a HTML template the DOM you want to keep injecting, similar to this:

```
var template = '<div class="clone_box_holder cloneEmp"><p><label><strong>New Text</strong></label><textarea class="mceSimple" name="content[]"></textarea><div class="clear"></div></p></div>';
```

> I have removed the id attribute of the text area, see note on the
>   bottom of post.

Instead of cloning the existing *already* injected tinyMCE DOM elements, only inject your template and then re-attach the tinyMCE plug-in to include the new DOM elements.

It seems the tinyMCE plugin get's confused when cloning already injected tinyMCE editors.
You only inject your basic DOM elements and let the tinyMCE plugin do the rest, that seems to work best.

I have done a very, very basic version of this, removing most of you unique code in relevance to the `textarea` id attribute changes to only focus on the relevant code.

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SL5xW/) - Injecting tinyMCE textareas dynamically

---

Try to incorporate this in your code.

> Remove the text area id as it only causes problems, even when changing
>   it in the code. You always know the context of the current textarea when you click
>   into it anyway.

Complete demo code for convinience:

```
var template = '<div class="clone_box_holder cloneEmp"><p><label><strong>New Text</strong></label><textarea class="mceSimple" name="content[]"></textarea><div class="clear"></div></p></div>';

function initTinyMCE() {
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "textareas",
        theme: "simple"
    });
}

(function ($) {
    $.fn.relCopy = function (options) {
        var settings = jQuery.extend({
            excludeSelector: ".exclude",
            emptySelector: ".empty",
            copyClass: "copy",
            append: '',
            clearInputs: true,
            limit: 0 // 0 = unlimited
        }, options);

        settings.limit = parseInt(settings.limit);

        // loop each element
        this.each(function () {

            // set click action
            $(this).click(function () {                
                var $clone = $(template);

                $('form').find('.cloneEmp:last').after($clone);

                initTinyMCE(); // re-attach plug-in to include new DOM

                return false;
            }); // end click action

        }); //end each loop

        return this; // return to jQuery
    };

})(jQuery);


$(function () {
    var removeLink = ' <a class="remove" href="#" style="float:right; margin-top:-20px; margin-bottom:10px;" onclick="$(this).parent().slideUp(function(){ $(this).remove() }); return false">remove</a>';
    $('a.add').relCopy({
        append: removeLink
    });
});

initTinyMCE();
```

Comment: I understand this might be a bit out of the scope of the question but would be grateful if you could help check it out. Wanna ask if you tried testing the generated textarea content within the form via PHP to see the output? Cos I just did a while ago. I generated additional textarea and added content in all & on submission of the form via PHP, only the text within the last textarea was submitted. The preceding textarea were not gotten. Apparently, the last textarea over-writes the preceding ones.. Still trying to get it to work. Hope to get a response from you. Thanks!

Comment: @user2332411: I don't know PhP (.net person myself) but I see if I can get a working example together in either a fiddle or locally. In general I think the name property is used to set the key when the data is serialized and if they all have the same name a list of same named keys with their values is sent. If in PhP it binds it to a collection/list of that name automatically like in .net I don't know.

Comment: Alright. Basically, Php binds all the data to the name property which is set as an array and you can then fetch all the list out. But based on this issue, it's apparent that the tinymce textarea being generated is not being serialized or rather it's using the Id for all the textareas that's generated instead of creating several unique instances of it. Would be pleased if you could test it locally via .Net to see if it's working. Look forward to getting a response from you. Thanks!

Comment: @Ous: Using tinyMCE in .net I had to do 2 things: Rename the textarea `name` from content[]` to `content` (in template too) as c# parameter names cannot contain `[]` and manually call `tinyMCE.triggerSave();` when re-binding tinyMCE. My action was `[ValidateInput(false)]public ActionResult TinyMceTest(string[] content){return view;}` both, the network tab in the browser console and a breakpoint at the start of the method did show both content were passed and received. I had no `id` attributes set in any textarea.

Comment: @Ous: The network tab shows: `FORM DATA: content:<p>sdfsdsdfsdf</p> content:<p>4564654</p>` and both were received in .NET. **What form data does your network tab show was posted?** Even an id on textarea still uses the name attribute when posting data. Also when not calling `tinyMCE.triggerSave();` manually **before** re-binding `tinyMCE.init(...)` it cleared the last tinyMCE instance instead of saving it to the hidden textarea. I had a simple `<button type="submit">Submit</button>` in the form, so nothing special there either. I'm not sure why it doesn't send the data for you as expected :(

Comment: Really appreciate your detailed response. Still on it though, trying to get it to work based on your suggestions. The form data that was posted was just the last textarea value and I have also tried removing the [] from content and also call the editor save method tinyMCE.triggerSave() but not getting it. Guess I'm missing somethings out. If this would not be asking for too much, Could you post the updates you made on the js and also your .Net code used in handling the form data. That would really help. Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49554/discussion-between-francois-wahl-and-ous)